# RubyOnRails4 How do I exclude properties from a has_many relationship when rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to exclude properties from :jobs like I've done with @databases?  I'm new to ruby and rails so I suspect (read: hope) that my syntax is wrong and this is an easy problem to fix.

```
wants.json { render :json => @databases, :include => [:jobs], :except => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `@databases` object's model class `has_many :jobs` then, you can do:

```
render :json => @databases.to_json(:include => {:jobs => {:except => [:created_at, updated_at]}}, :except => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Added `=> { :except => [:id] }` to `:jobs`

```
wants.json { render :json => @databases, :include => [:jobs => { :except => [:id] }, :except => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at] }
```